# Relationship and referential integrity constraint using JPA

Tags: java, mysql, database, hibernate, jpa

I started to design my Java EE application using MySQL and JPA for persistence, so I have a doubt to how implent it for database design.

So I defined my database tables e.g: employees and departments with his relationship

Using JPA I defined relationship following some tutorials but I can't understand if foreign keys and constraints have to be defined too for database tables or left it without as:

```
CREATE TABLE `thejavageek`.`employee` (
  `idemployee` INT         NOT NULL,
  `firstname`  VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `lastname`   VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  # ...
PRIMARY KEY (`idemployee`)
);
```

And JPA entities:

```
@Entity
public class Employee{

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue( strategy= GenerationType.AUTO )     

   private int eid;
   private String ename;
   private double salary;
   private String deg;

   @ManyToOne
   private Department department;

   public Employee(int eid, String ename, double salary, String deg) {
      super( );
      this.eid = eid;
      this.ename = ename;
      this.salary = salary;
      this.deg = deg;
   }

   public Employee( ) {
      super();
   }

   public int getEid( ) {
      return eid;
   }

   public void setEid(int eid)  {
      this.eid = eid;
   }

   public String getEname( ) {
      return ename;
   }

   public void setEname(String ename) {
      this.ename = ename;
   }

   public double getSalary( ) {
      return salary;
   }

   public void setSalary(double salary) {
      this.salary = salary;
   }

   public String getDeg( ) {
      return deg;
   }

   public void setDeg(String deg) {
      this.deg = deg;
   }

   public Department getDepartment() {
      return department;
   }

   public void setDepartment(Department department) {
      this.department = department;
   }
}

@Entity
public class Department {

   @Id 
   @GeneratedValue( strategy=GenerationType.AUTO )

   private int id;
   private String name;

   public int getId() {
      return id;
   }

   public void setId(int id) {
      this.id = id;
   }

   public String getName( ){
      return name;
   }

   public void setName( String deptName ){
      this.name = deptName;
   }
}
```

lefting relationship and constraint management to JPA?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code system will create a new table by name `employee_department_mapping` (with `employee_id`, `department_id` columns in it) which will contain a mapping of every employee to its department.

However, if you want to handle it as a foreign key in employee table, mark your `department` field with `@JoinColumn` and tell the name of foreign key column

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "department_id")
private Department department;
```

And set `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `update`

Now if you will restart the application, it will automatically generate the foreign key column by name department_id in the employee table.

Comment: thanks for reply @naresh-joshi so I don't need to do define any foreign key in MySQL only create table with or whitout defining primary key?

Comment: and delegate to ORM all creation and management? can you post an example or a link please?

Comment: You don't even need to create your tables, just create an empty schema and hibernate will do all things, You can follow this video tutorial series to understand it https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4AFF701184976B25